# Custom label text on ngx pie chart

Tags: angular, typescript, pie-chart, ngx-charts

Is it possible to change the labels that are on an NGX Pie Chart?

You can see what I mean by labels in the picture below and also in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-pie-chart?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

I would like to pass an array with four elements containing custom text, for example the percentage value as a string.

I checked [this documentation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/pie-charts/pie-chart), but there does not seem to be an option to do what I described.

[image: LabelsHighlighted]